# Searching for child element by the value of one of its properties

Tags: javascript, xml, utf-8, wsh, getelementsbytagname

I'm extracting data from a TMX - an xml-based translation memory file. The file looks like this (`<tu>` entries are multiple, one for each translated string):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header creationtool="Multilizer" creationtoolversion="6.2.19" datatype="PlainText" segtype="sentence" adminlang="en" srclang="*all*" o-tmf="MLProject">
  </header>
  <body>
    <tu>
      <prop type="context">..\..\BuildProcess\Support_Files\CommonFiles\PSRIP\AlambicEdit.dll.Strings.126.2000</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en-CA">
        <seg>Error initializing library: %s.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>Error initializing library: %s.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="fr">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>Erreur lors de l'initialisation de la librairie %s.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="de">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>Fehler bei der Initialisierung der Bibliothek: %s.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="es">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>Error inicializando biblioteca: %s.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="it">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>Errore di inizializzazione libreria: %s.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="ja">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>ライブラリ初期化時のエラー: %s</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="zh-CN">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>初始化库时出错:%s。</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="pt">
        <prop type="status">tsQAed</prop>
        <seg>Erro ao inicializar biblioteca: %s.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

I need to extract specific languages in a specific order that's not always respected in the TMX, for instance the DE and ES languages are sometimes inverted.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to get a child element by the value of it's properties, so I can't do something like `segment = x.getElementsByPropertyValue("xml:lang", "en")` , which would be really awesome.

The only alternative I've found was to loop through *all* of the languages and check them against a properly sorted language array (which would be horribly slow on 600k+ entries in 10 different files).

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Is there such a method?

Note: I'm in WSH Javascript, so I have access to any ActiveXObject available in WSH...

Comment: Could you sort it server side with an XSLT transformation?

Comment: Could you get an XPath library use that to grab the elements in the right order?

Comment: XSLT is beyond my understanding, I haven't been able to wrap my head around that. Besides this is WSH, so technically it *is* server side... As for XPath libraries, I'm not so sure I know what that means. If you have examples or a link to a page with more details, I'd be willing to read up, though.

Comment: If you used an XPath library like [wicked-good-xpath](http://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/) (which I have never used) you could query your XML similar to `segment = x.getElementsByPropertyValue("xml:lang", "en")`.  But then the XPath library would just be looping over 600k+ entries internally, which you said could take a long time.  I couldn't help but notice that according to the first answer, [JQuery lets you query your XML files too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712311/jquery-query-xml-document-where-clause).  I would vote for that over XPath.

Comment: But both of these (jQuery and the wicked-good-xpath) are for browsers - not WSH. I can't load jQuery in the wsh, and the wicked page states that it enables ''XPath evaluation for HTML documents in every browser'' ... I don't think this applies to me

Comment: Well, I guess learning XSLT is not a waste of my time, considering how I was headdesking for hours. Couple of tutorials later.... I'll answer my own question (as I so often do...)

Answer (score 0):

If your environment supports [querySelector/querySelectorAll](http://caniuse.com/queryselector), try:

```
xmldoc.querySelector("tuv[xml\\:lang='es']");
```

If not, I am afraid looping is the only way. You could of course consider using a library like jQuery that does the looping for you.

Comment: That would be perfect... but I'm not in a browser. Do you have any idea if this support can be added (I don't mind what I have to do to load it, this isn't production stuff, it's a one-off thing) to the WSH environment in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Because all I needed was to put things in the right order, I guess it's not the worse thing in the world to simply learn a bit of XSLT, enough to transform the file into what I needed. Thankfully, XSLT can output to text which was one of my options, and it's *blazing* fast compared to JavaScript... Here's my solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="tmx/body/tu">
   <xsl:text>[EN]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'en']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[FR]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'fr']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[ES]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'es']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[DE]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'de']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[IT]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'it']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[PT]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'pt']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[JA]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'ja']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[ZH]   </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="tuv[@xml:lang = 'zh-CN']/seg"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[CAP]  Yes&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[PL]   MyProduct#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[DPT]  &#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[REG]  &#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[SOU]  Terminology Extraction&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[NOT]  </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="prop"/><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[HIS]  EL 2013/09/18&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[~]&#13;&#13;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'll admit it's not elegant or compact, but as long as it works, and since this is a one-time process... it's acceptable.